# Can the slope of an Excel trendline be used as a measure of change?

Tags: excel, statistics, trendline

In an effort to try and capture the trend of student enrollment over several years worth of data, I'm trying to determine if the slope of a trendline in Excel can be calculated.

Here is some data:

[image]

My first attempts at using the SLOPE function yield values that extend beyond the -90/90 degrees I would expect:

[image]

And here are the corresponding scatter plots with trendlines - the colours are the same in the table as the chart:

[image]

The SLOPE values -1.5 and -35 seem similar to the trendline - but the other values of 185 and 92 don't correspond.

I understand the SLOPE is not performing the same calculation as the trendline is showing, so I'm wondering if there is a function / process to create that line.

Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Slope does not return degrees. it returns a coefficient: `y=ax + b` it returns the `a`.  It is part of the trend line formula.

As you can see if we put the formulas for the trend lines on the chart:

[image]

To get `b` you will need the `INTERCEPT()` formula;

```
=INTERCEPT(B2:B7,$A$2:$A$7)
```

[image]

Then using those two values, one can use the following to do a forecast:

```
=B8*$A$11+B9
```

[image]

Or simply use the FORCAST.LINEAR() function:

```
=FORECAST.LINEAR($A$12,B2:B7,$A$2:$A$7)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this!!! Greatly appreciated. What I'm trying to do is use the angle of the trendline as a proxy for a measure of change. In general, if the trendline applied to the scatterplot goes slightly 'down', that might mean an angle of let's say -15 degrees. I would then use that as a value to plot on a geographic map of schools. The value for 2019 isn't really important at this point, though the numbers in the table of values could incorporate data from our projections and forecasting for the same outcome.